# Using Custom Function with multiple parameters and partitioning/grouping by a column

Tags: python, python-polars

Is it possible to do something like the following in python polars:

```
import polars as pl
import statsmodels.api as sm
lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess
df = pl.DataFrame([pl.Series('x', ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b']),
    pl.Series('y', [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]),
    pl.Series('z', [.2, .3, .5, .1, .3, .7])]
)
df.with_columns([
    pl.struct(['z', 'y']).map(lambda cols: pl.DataFrame(lowess(cols['z'], cols['y'], frac = .1))).over('x')
])
```

I want to group by one or more columns and then apply a function with more than 1 argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With window function `.over()` you should use `.apply()` function. To reach specific field of `struct` you can use `.struct.field()` [method](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.field.html).

```py
def get_lowess(s: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    return pl.Series(
        lowess(s.struct.field("z"), s.struct.field("y"), frac = .1)
    )

df.with_columns([
    pl.struct(['z', 'y']).apply(get_lowess).over('x').alias("lowess")
])
```

Comment: Forgot to add `pl.Series()`

Comment: Thanks! that works as I wanted. Is there a way to do this with map? I thought apply is for row-wise operations and not columnar.

Comment: It seems that `map` (in comparison with `apply`) takes the entire column and `over` does not affect on it.

Comment: In this case `apply` is not row-wise (if you add `print(s)` for `get_lowess` function, you will see that it operates with `Series`)))

Comment: @troh ["apply works on the smallest logical elements for that operation"](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html#to-apply) is where it is documented if that helps.

Comment: @jqurious The documentation isn't very clear. I'm not using ```group_by``` so is that not saying it would apply it for each element and not the series?

Comment: @troh `.over()` is also a groupby context.