# How to send additional arguments when using polars.Expr.apply

Tags: python-polars

I want to use polars.Expr.apply to perform an operation on a Polars DataFrame column. I need to send additional argument. How do I send it?

Comment: Can you give more information? `apply` is slower, maybe it can be done in the native API. If you really need to use `apply`, [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is probably the way to go as far as adding additional arguments.

Comment: Essentially you want to put the columns in a struct then you write your function or lambda expression to extract the underlying columns from within the struct. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303247/1818713)

Comment: or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75364542/1818713)

Comment: or [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71679606/1818713)